# Updating global variable from eventlistener

Tags: javascript, global-variables, video.js, event-listener

I'm trying to gather the times of all videos on a page and add them to an array. Here is the code:

```
var allvideos = $('video');
var times = [];
for ( i=0; i < allvideos.length; i++ ) {
    allvideos[i].addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        videoDuration = this.duration;
        times.push(videoDuration);
    });
};
```

If I console.log(times) within the EventListener, it works as expected but if I log it after the for loop it's empty. I can't figure out why that is. Could someone help, and please explain why? Thanks so much.

I am using jQuery and Video.js.

S

Comment: Why would you expect it to be not empty before the event listeners are called ?

Comment: Simple. You are placing buckets to collect rain water. Then you expect that all the buckets will be filled immediately after placing them. Please wait until it rains :)

Comment: So in my case, how do I wait?

Comment: @Stu in each event listener's callback function you need to check if all the other event listeners have been executed. One way to do this is to check if `times.length === allvideos.length`. See my answer for some code.

Answer (score 3):

Think about how your code is executing:

1. Create `times` array
2. Set up event listeners
3. Output the value in the `times` array with a console.log
4. Event listeners are called and push to `times` array

The reason it is not showing the `videoDuration`s in the `times` array is because `times` is empty at that point in time. You have to wait until after all your event listeners have been called before outputting the values in the array.

---

If you want to output the array after all your event listeners have been called, then you can do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allvideos.length; i++) {
    allvideos[i].addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        times.push(this.duration);

        if (times.length === allvideos.length) {
            console.log(times);
        }
    });
};
```